# Search bar in TableHeaderView with wrong behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I added a search bar in my tableView and the search bar disappears when pressed.

here is a gif with the wrong behavior:

[image]

and here is my simple code:

```
import UIKit

class UMSearchBarViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Try this line `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: **Tested in Swift 3.**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // If this is your main controller.try this code inside your viewDidload 
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false // If you don't want this happend when swipe.
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
}
```

**Note:** Dont forget to Auto Constrains your searcher.